# Does CTreeCtrl::SortChildren() change handles of childs?

Tags: c++, mfc

I keep `HTREEITEM` for `CTreeCtrl` items in some classes. I only want to know whether `CTreeCtrl::SortChildren()` changes `HTREEITEM`-handles of childs? After i use `CTreeCtrl::SortChildren()`, will be old tree item handles valid?

I couldn't find anything officially. I think that won't change handles, but i want to be sure.

Comment: I don't see any official documentation on this, either, including in the SDK's `TVM_SORTCHILDREN` message that this wrapper function is based on. But the only way that it could possibly invalidate the handle is if it sorted by *destroying* each item and *recreating* it. And I cannot imagine any good reason for doing that, when it could just remove the item and reinsert it at the desired position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing officially, but as i see from my tests, tree item handle, which is sorted child, won't be changed after `CTreeCtrl::SortChildren()`.